# Set height of header with header image for print

Tags: html, css, printing

I've got a header image and a header height.
I want to include the header image on every page during print.

And the page content should start at header height from top. (The header height includes the header image.)

Similarly, I want for footer-image and footer-height.

I tried out the following:

CSS :

```
@media print {
    .divHeader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: {header-height};
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="divHeader">
    <img src="" width="100%" />
</div>
<-- Page content to print -->
```

This brings header image to every print page but does not give the gap before page content according to header-height.

What is missing here?

Comment: Does it work in anyway if using `padding-bottom: 25mm;` or `margin-bottom:25mm;` in the CSS for `.divHeader`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The page content starts from top, and the header image overlaps it.

Comment: Then define `margin-top` for the page container only in the print CSS.

Comment: This works but ONLY for the first page. Gap is added in first page but not in subsequent pages.

Comment: Try putting a Div in between `.divHeader` and your content. The Div will be empty and have a `height: 0;` on all screen media queries and breakpoints. Then a defined height in MM for the print media query? Would need to go on all your pages of course.

Comment: The pages are automatically split based on content size, I have no control on the pages.
Isn't there a way to set height in the header itself instead of the page content ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this library: [paged.js](https://pagedjs.org/). It's a polyfill for the currently not supported [css page media module level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#first-pseudo).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32717514)